# pgbench: generating a random padded string

Tags: postgresql, benchmark

I have the IMDb database in PostgreSQL 16, and I am trying to generate random strings for performance benchmark. The relevant table is `title_basics` with the primary key column `tconst`, VARCHAR(9). `tconst` has values in the form of 'tt0000000', where the zeroes represent numbers, e.g., 'tt0000001' and 'tt9999999'.

I want to write an .sql file which can be run with pgbench, which generates random, padded numbers appended after the string 'tt', e.g.:

`SELECT * FROM title_basics WHERE tconst = 'tt0000001';`

With simple SQL, this would be trivial, but since pgbench supports only a small number of scalar functions, it seems difficult. I have also explored the use of SQL in the pgbench script, but constructs such as this do not seem to be supported:

```
\set random_number (SELECT random());
```

or:

```
\set random_number :randint(0, 9999999)
\set padding_length 7 - length(:'random_number')
\set primary_key 'tt' || repeat('0', :'padding_length') || :'random_number'
```

I also considered generating the numbers with SQL, but this effectively prevents PostgreSQL from using the index on tconst. I do not want to create an additional index to satisfy the query, as that would be problematic for other reasons.

```
SELECT * 
FROM title_basics 
WHERE tconst = 'tt' || LPAD((FLOOR(RANDOM()*(9916880 - 1 + 1)) + 1)::text, 7, '0');
```

Edit:

I found a somewhat functional solution of generating the random value in a CTE. This does not prevent PostgreSQL from using the index on tconst. However, I would be happy to see a more pgbench-oriented approach.

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT 'tt' || LPAD((FLOOR(RANDOM()*(9916880 - 1 + 1)) + 1)::text, 7, '0') AS tconst_random
)
SELECT * 
FROM title_basics, a 
WHERE tconst = a.tconst_random;
```

Comment: If you enclose `random()` in a subquery, like `(SELECT random())`, it will be executed only once. Otherwise, it will produce a different value for each row, and no index scan can be used.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you, that is a much more scalable approach, as the "solution" in my original post creates a cartesian product and does not seem to scale to more complex queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random()` in a `WHERE` condition will be executed for each row, returning a different value every time, which prevents the use of an index scan.

The traditional workaround is a subquery: if that does not reference any outside columns, it is executed only once (`InitPlan`), so that the result is constant and an index can be used.

Replace `random()` with `(SELECT random())`.